# How to get library files of MySQL 5.5 in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, file

I have header files of MySQL 5.5:

```
 decimal.h   m_string.h      my_dbug.h    my_list.h        my_sys.h     mysql_embed.h    mysqld_error.h  sql_state.h        typelib.h
    errmsg.h    my_alloc.h      my_dir.h     my_net.h         my_xml.h     mysql_time.h     raid.h          sslopt-case.h
    keycache.h  my_attribute.h  my_getopt.h  my_no_pthread.h  mysql.h      mysql_version.h  readline.h      sslopt-longopts.h
    m_ctype.h   my_config.h     my_global.h  my_pthread.h     mysql_com.h  mysqld_ername.h  sql_common.h    sslopt-vars.h
```

But I don't have library files. I need it. Can anyone please tell me what I need to do to get it:

These files are supposed to be in library folder:

```
    libdbug.a    libmyisammrg.a      libmysqlclient.so@         libmysqlclient_r.a    libmysqlclient_r.so.15@      libmysys.a
libheap.a    libmysqlclient.a    libmysqlclient.so.15@      libmysqlclient_r.la*  libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0*  libvio.a
libmyisam.a  libmysqlclient.la*  libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0*  libmysqlclient_r.so@  libmystrings.a
```

Comment: check /usr/include/mysql/ folder

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the information needed about where is your **mysql header file or lib files** etc.

Just enter `mysql_config` in the terminal and it will output something like this:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -pipe -Wno-uninitialized  -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing]
        --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
        --libs           [-L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl]
        --plugindir      [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
        --socket         [/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [10.0.14]
        --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/lib -lmysqld]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/include/mysql]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/lib]
                plugindir     [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
```

You can see the **include** and **libs** options and there is the path in front of it mentioning its location.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution. Install LAMP or Xampp.
[Lamp](http://www.lamphowto.com/) : Linux - Apache - Mysql - Php
[Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html/) : Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, and Solaris - Apache - Mysql - Php - Perl
This installs Mysql and Php without any hassles.

Comment: Can you help me in uninstalling the mysql every part. So that, I can start installing XAMPP

Comment: Try these links. http://www.clan-elite.info/forum.asp?action=view_thread&id=910     http://superuser.com/questions/297176/uninstall-mysql-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you don't able type `$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` on your Ubuntu you may download and install completely MySql Server 5.5 package from here http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads (Select Platform: Debian Linux)

After the installation you can find all needed libraries in the server "bin" folder.

For example see the following post:
http://akbarahmed.com/2012/04/08/install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-running-in-the-rackspace-cloud-2/

Comment: Can you help me in uninstalling the mysql every part(library files, configuration, haeader files.) so that I can follow the instructions to get everything done.